# How to automate response to console message from an R function?

Tags: r

I'm working with an R function that occasionally prompts the user with a message in the console, asking for input. Specifically, I'm using the tabla.frecuencias function from the "estadistica" package, which asks whether the user wants to group values into intervals.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(estadistica)
tabla.frecuencias(mtcars$mpg)
```

How can I automate the response to this console message within my R script, without requiring manual intervention? I've tried using capture_output and tryCatch, but haven't had success.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [source](https://rdrr.io/cran/estadistica/src/R/tabla.frecuencias.R) to define a version of the function that uses arguments rather than interactive prompts:

```r
tabla.frecuencias.auto <- function(x,
                                   eliminar.na = TRUE,
                                   grafico = FALSE,
                                   exportar = FALSE,
                                   nombre = "variable",  ### ADDED ARG
                                   agrupar = FALSE       ### ADDED ARG
                                   ){
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  varnames <- colnames(x)
  if(length(x) > 1 ) {
    ### REMOVE:
    # variable <- readline(prompt = "Intoduce el nombre de la variable: ")
    ### ADD:
    variable <- nombre 
    ###
  # ...
  # ...
  if (valores_distintos >= 20){
    ### REMOVE:
    # print("La variable presenta muchos valores distintos (20 o mas)")
    # agrupar <- as.numeric(readline('\u00bfQuieres agrupar los valores en intervalos?: \n 1. "S\u00ed, agrupar en intervalos." \n 2. "No, usar los valores sin agrupar." \n'))
    ### ADD:
    agrupar <- if (agrupar) 1 else 2
    ###
  # ...
  # ...
}
```

Honestly I don’t think relying on interactive prompts for this kind of function is great design, as you’ve discovered — you might consider asking the package maintainers if they’d consider adding arguments instead or as an alternative.